# Meteor: What payment processors should I use for UK based company?

Tags: meteor, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I'm wanting to take payments online.  I've noticed that since the Meteor 0.9.0 update the Paypal package is now incompatible.  I was intending integrating Paypal but that doesn't look possible at the moment, certainly not with that package anyway.

Does anyone know of any easy to integrate payment processors that I can use with Meteor?

Thank you

Comment: Don't you think the better way is to fork the Paypal package so that it works again rather than trying to find something random? Most packages broke with Meteor 0.9, so it's better to start somewhere.

Comment: Plus, most of those broken packages will get updates in the near future. Also, you can temporarily use Paypal Node / Javascript libraries instead of a package, or pack them yourself.

Comment: Forking the Paypal package may be an option but I might be out of my depth.  I'll have a think about my options before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Go with [stripe.com](http://www.stripe.com/)
looks very promising!